# datatype text not support

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have huge data file and one of the column is text and has large data set in that column.

I tried to create column with text data type but it is not supported.

How to bring text data type data over to databricks.

please guide

Answer (score 0):

Here's reference: [Databricks data types](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datatypes.html)

For CHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT and, in general, character strings of any size, just use [STRING](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/string-type.html).

Comment: Hello thank you for the update. I tried that, i also tried to cast or convert as varchar8000 but the files data is huge and it is medical history notes so still having issues migrating data to delta table. any suggestion???

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise about "having issues". Exact schemas, code, errors.